# to remove a particular pattern, and some lines above or below it

Tags: linux, unix

`a
b
rat
c
d
banana
w
e
r
mango
cat 
f`
 this is the easiest representation of input file that contains some patterns(say banana) in large amount. I want to remove the pattern, 2 lines above it and 3 lines below it. grep and awk command did not work for me. I am unable to that work manually. How to proceed since I have 50 files and more than 100 patterns in each file!

expected output:

`a
b
rat
mango
cat 
f`

Comment: Use python or your preferred scripting language. The linux utils operate on lines as a fundamental unit. Awk is a full featured programming language, but a scripting language makes it easier.

Comment: but how will I remove lines above and below the pattern. The lines in the input files may change so I can not use a for loop too.

Comment: You need to use a list and remove the elements from the list before and after you find the element. If you can't define the problem well enough for a program to do it with a forloop, you won't find a Linux util to do it.